# `findChessboardCorners` not working for webcam video (python)

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to get [this git repo](https://github.com/pperle/gaze-tracking-pipeline) to work locally but am stuck on the calibration part.
If you look at `camera_calibration.py` it records a webcam video, changes it to grayscale and then calls `findChessboardCorners` on each frame. However, since the whole point of this repo is to implement gaze-tracking, I'm confused on how to get the method to work on a video of my eye or whole face for example.

I tried running it with a video of my face and it's unable to find corners. I then tested it with an image of a chessboard where it works fine but doesn't make sense in the context of the code where we're trying to track gaze direction. Thank you!